# Swift array showing up empty after using completion handler

Tags: swift, firebase, swift5

I'm trying to fetch a list of services from a Firebase database. Here's my reference:

`let REF_SERVICES = DB_REF.child("services")`

Here's my fetch function:

```
func fetchServices(completion: @escaping([Service]) -> Void) {
    var services = [Service]()
    REF_SERVICES.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            guard let dictionary = child.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
            let title = child.key
            let service = Service(title: title, dictionary: dictionary)
            services.append(service)
        }
    }
    completion(services)
}
```

Here's the *Service* struct:

```
enum ServiceStatus: Int {
    case available
    case busy
}

struct Service {
    let title: String
    var details: String?
    var location: CLLocation?
    var status: ServiceStatus!

    init(title: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.title = title
        if let details = dictionary["details"] as? String {
            self.details = details
        }
        if let index = dictionary["status"] as? Int {
            self.status = ServiceStatus(rawValue: index)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know much about how completion handlers and asynchronous calls work, so I don't know how to get it to work.

Here's where I call this function in a ViewController:

```
private var services: [Service]? {
    didSet {
        let addServiceController = AddServiceController()
        addServiceController.services = self.services!
    }
}

func fetchServices() {
    Services.shared.fetchServices { (services) in
        self.services = services
    }
}
```

In both ViewControllers the array shows up empty. I've used the holy grail of debugging by using print statements to verify that it is fetching the data.

Thanks.

Comment: I am sure @arturdev 's answer is correct. by the way, I just wondered what does `didSet` of `services` property of your ViewController intend to do? It looks little bit weird that `addServiceController` is created in `didSet`. :-)

Comment: @KyokookHwang I instantiate it to access the `services` array in that ViewController. Though it would probably be better to just make the one in `HomeController` static to be able to be accessed in `AddServiceController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `completion(services)` call inside the completion callback of observe method.

```
func fetchServices(completion: @escaping([Service]) -> Void) {
    var services = [Service]()
    REF_SERVICES.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            guard let dictionary = child.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
            let title = child.key
            let service = Service(title: title, dictionary: dictionary)
            services.append(service)
        }
        completion(services) //<-- at this point services will contain the info you appended in for loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what arturdev said above, you need to put the completion inside the observe method. Firebase calls are async code, which basically means the code executes as fast as possible, and not top-to-bottom. So in your original function, the completion was getting called as right after REF_SERVICES was executed, and not after the code within the REF_SERVICES function.

I believe you also need to include a loop counter, otherwise the completion will execute only after 1 loop (again, async will execute as soon as possible).

A final tip would be to try to avoid using "as!" in your code and instead use an if let statement. If, for some reason, there is ever an issue in your database and the data couldn't be cast as [DataSnapshot], your app would crash.

Below code should work, but I haven't tested. Good luck!

```
func fetchServices(completion: @escaping (_ [Service]?) -> ()) {
    REF_SERVICES.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            var services = [Service]()
            var counter = 0
            for child in data {
                let title = child.key
                if let dictionary = child.value as? [String : Any] {
                    let service = Service(title: title, dictionary: dictionary)
                    services.append(service)
                    counter = counter + 1
                    if counter == data.count {
                        completion(services)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("There was an error casting dictionary for \(title)")
                    counter = counter + 1
                    if counter == data.count {
                        completion(services)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Could not cast data as [DataSnapshot]")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```